# How to switch xmonad workspace and notify the current workspace's tag or name under full screen without bar?

Tags: xmonad

I connfig the xmonad workspaces as follows

```
myWorkspaces = map show [1..20 :: Int]

[((mod4Mask .|. m, k), windows $ f i)
| (i, k) <- zip myWorkspaces ([xK_1 .. xK_9] ++ [xK_0] ++ [xK_F1 .. xK_F10])
, (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask), (copy, mod3Mask)]
]
```

And I want to use notify-send shell command to show the current workspace number when switch to a certain workspace.

So how to define a function to `greedyView` the workspace and show the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved the problem by myself.

```
[((mod4Mask .|. m, k), workspaceHint f i)
    | (i, k) <- zip myWorkspaces ([xK_1 .. xK_9] ++ [xK_0] ++ [xK_F1 .. xK_F10])
    , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask), (copy, mod3Mask)]
    ]

notifyWSHint :: String -> X()
notifyWSHint index = spawn $ "notify-send -t 500 \"workspace: " ++ index ++ "\""

workspaceHint f i = do
  windows $ f i
  notifyWSHint i
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.